# kohana query show latest record only

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

OK so basically I am creating a pm inbox in my kohana project

So far I have been able to retrieve the messages without an issue with this query

```
$messages = DB::select('users.username', 'users.id', 'profiles.profile_picture', 'messages.thread', 'messages.subject', 'messages.content', array('messages.id', 'mid'))->from('messages')->join('users', 'LEFT')->on('users.id', '=', 'messages.from_id')
                ->join('profiles', 'LEFT')->on('profiles.user_id', '=', 'messages.from_id')->where('messages.to_id', '=', $user)->and_where('messages.deleted', '=', '0')->execute();
```

My question is I would like to only show the last message if there is multiple from the same user. Should this be done in the query or with php when rendering the results.

I have a date column I think I can use for this, but I am not sure the best approach.

Thanks

Comment: You can order by date DESC and LIMIT 1

Comment: I am not trying to limit the results. Basically I want group by from_id , but return the last message and not the first, as that what happens when I try to add ->group_by('messages.from_id')

Comment: Try GROUP BY from_id DESC, not sure how to do that with kohana, just try by hand if it brings you the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

```
$messages = DB::select('users.username', 'users.id', 'profiles.profile_picture', 'messages.thread', 'messages.subject', 'messages.content', array('messages.id', 'mid'))
  ->from('messages')
  ->join('users', 'LEFT')->on('users.id', '=', 'messages.from_id')
  ->join('profiles', 'LEFT')->on('profiles.user_id', '=', 'messages.from_id')
  ->where('messages.to_id', '=', $user)
  ->and_where('messages.deleted', '=', '0')
  ->order_by('messages.id', 'desc')
  ->offset(0)
  ->limit(1)
  ->execute();
```